# Configuring Magical Unicorn Mvc Error Toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-errors

I am trying to configure the Magical Unicorn Mvc Error Toolkit (v 2.1.2) on my MVC4 web site but I can't get it to work.  Here's my code:

**Web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ServerError">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Views/Error/NotFound.cshtml" />
</customErrors>

<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
     <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
     <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
     <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>
<system.webServer>
```

**Error Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        return View();
    }
}
```

[These were based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499406/236860 post]

**CustomerErrorHandler.cs (App_Start)**

```
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using WorldDomination.Web.Mvc;
using CustomErrors.App_Start;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(CustomErrorHander), "PreStart")]
namespace CustomErrors.App_Start
{
    public static class CustomErrorHander
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            // Register the custom error handling module.
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof (CustomErrorHandlingModule));
        }
    }
}
```

I am testing this application in Visual Studio 2012 using IIS Express. If I try to navigate to a non-existent page, or go to an action method that calls an exception I either get the default browser error page or a blank page.

I have also modified the above code as suggested at [ASP.NET MVC Custom Error Pages with Magical Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155837/asp-net-mvc-custom-error-pages-with-magical-unicorn) but this dis not seem to make any difference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the end, I could not get the Magical Unicorn Mvc Error Toolkit to work.  The good news is that I don't think I had to!  Since I am deploying the MVC application to an IIS 7.5 web server, I could use the later system.webServer.httpErrors section of my Web.config and a custom error controller.

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
    <customErrors mode="Off" />   <!-- IMPORTANT -->
    ...
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ApplicationError" />
    </httpErrors>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

**Error Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult AccessDenied()
   {
      Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
      Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        // return Json friendly response here
      }

      return View();
   }

   public ActionResult NotFound()
   {
      Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
      Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        // return Json friendly response here
      }

      return View();
   }

   public ActionResult ApplicationError()
   {
      Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
      Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      {
        // return Json friendly response here
      }

      return View();
   }
}
```

- This all seems to work well with IIS Express and IIS 7.5.
- Elmah logs the errors without any changes to the default error filters.
- Fiddler also suggests that the correct HTTP Status codes are also being correctly maintained.

Comment: After wasting time with the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc, it turns out this is an excellent approach that just plain works.

Comment: Thank you Michael, glad it was of help.